# How to read XML in blue prism?

Tags: xml, robotics

How to get value from specific node in XML document in blue prism?

I have imported file management and strings file from VBO folder. But using that I am not able to get value from specific node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually with the help of  file management and strings file from VBO folder, I got all xml data into text data item, after that using code(Regular c# code) I got value from specific node. It works..

Answer (score 2):

There is already one inbuilt "XML VBO" provided by blue prism,you can download the VBO in Blue prism portal.By using that VBO you can achieve almost everything about xml.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try to import the MS Excel VBO? Inside that VBO, theres a lot of Excel related objects that might help you.

Comment: I am not sure whether it is possible with MS Excel VBO, but its surely possible with file management and string  files inside VBO.